# What is the correct way to connect a dropdown.onselect to server backend

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.net 4.5, MVC.

I understand how to do all the usual MVC stuff.

In my navbar, I have a small dropdown which allows a user to change "location".
When then select a new location from the dropdown, I need to tell the session variable to update, then reload the page they are on.

I can think of 3 ways to do this:

1. Hook some javascript to the dropdown, do an AJAX call to a special controller.
2. Do some kind of formsubmit to the same page and somehow catch it in the usual controller.
3. Use razor to write the functionality inside the HTML page (Seems wrong because it would be the wrong place to put logic).

What would be a simple way to implement this functionality? I want this to change straight away when the use clicks the location - no "Submit" button per say.

Comment: For performance, Option 1 is best. Option 3 cannot work - you need to respond to client side events (the dropdownlist's `.change()` event of the form's `submit()` event) and razor is server side code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this one way, which is why I will post this as *an* answer.

I wrote the view as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        @SessionHandler.UserSession.ValidFactories[SessionHandler.UserSession.SelectedFactoryIndex].Name
             <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        @for (var i = 0; i < SessionHandler.UserSession.ValidFactories.Count; i++)
        {<li><a href = /Home/ChangeFactory?id=@i>@SessionHandler.UserSession.ValidFactories[i].Name</a></li>}
        </ul>
</div>
```

This means I am submitting the click of the dropdown as an ID to the *Home* controllers *ChangeFactory* action/function.

```
public ActionResult changeFactory(int id)
    {

        SessionHandler.UserSession.SelectedFactoryIndex = id;

        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
```

Changes the session, then returns the user to exactly where they were. Very fast. I know this will be pushing to the "History" in the browser but its fine for now. Please post other solutions if you have them.

Comment: Since nobody else seems to be responding, I'm making my response the answer.